# Query giving all the record need to generate latest record from history table

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

Need to get latest record from history table while joining with table.

[image]

when I am doing query with below

```
select * from Product, ProductHistory where Product.ProductNo=ProductNo.ProductNo
```

It gives all the record what I need is latest record from ProductHistory table

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am joining but it has more than one record for same product. I need to get latest history record

Comment: Hint: Join a subquery to get the max order date for each ProductNo

Answer (score 2):

**untested**

Here's how I would do it:

start with a subquery to get the "latest" date for each Product:

```
select ProductNo, max(Date)
from ProductHistory
group by ProductNo
```

Then you have to join that result to the ProductHistory table to get the corresponding "Transaction":

```
select PH.ProductNo, PH.Transaction, PH.Date
from (
   select ProductNo, max(Date)
   from ProductHistory
   group by ProductNo
) MaxPH
inner join ProductHistory PH
   on PH.ProductNo = MaxPH.ProductNo
   and PH.Date = MaxPH.Date
```

Finally, join the Product table to get the Product (name)

```
select P.Product, P.ProductNo, PH.Transaction, PH.Date
from (
   select ProductNo, max(Date)
   from ProductHistory
   group by ProductNo
) MaxPH
inner join ProductHistory PH
   on PH.ProductNo = MaxPH.ProductNo
   and PH.Date = MaxPH.Date
inner join Product P on P.ProductNo = PH.ProductNo
```

You could also use row numbers with a partition to find the "lastest".

Comment: by adding subquery it is performing very bad, there is any other way of doing this? Thanks!